# 2 questions regarding socket programming with Android

Tags: android

I've taken examples I've found on the internet for socket programming, and am trying to build my own Android client for a an Ethernet-enabled Arduino server. I have 2 problems however.
First, the code for my main activity:

```
package com.domiflichi.TesterProject;

import java.io.BufferedWriter; // output
import java.io.BufferedReader; // input
import java.io.InputStreamReader; // input
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; // output
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;







public class TesterProjectMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

private Button connectPhones;

private TextView myTextView; // represents the 'status text'

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;


private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.client);


connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);

connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
connectPhones.setOnClickListener(this);



myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

}



// This was created when using the 'implements OnClickListener' in the class
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.connect_phones) {
if (!connected) {
serverIpAddress = "192.168.0.178";
if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
cThread.start();
connectPhones.setEnabled(false); // Once the button is pressed, disable it. :)
}
}

} else if (v.getId() == R.id.status_req) {
// CODE HERE FOR STATUS REQUEST BUTTON?

} else if (v.getId() == R.id.cmd_toggle) {
// CODE HERE FOR TOGGLE DOOR BUTTON?

} else if (v.getId() == R.id.cmd_crack) {
// CODE HERE FOR CRACK BUTTON?

} else if (v.getId() == R.id.disconnect) {
// CODE HERE FOR DISCONNECT BUTTON?

}
}





public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

public void run() {
try {
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 23);
connected = true;

while (connected) {
try {
Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println("mypass*");
Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");





BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
final StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
total.append(line);
Log.d("Server response", line.toString());

}





handler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {


if (total.toString().contentEquals("status:open")) {

myTextView.setText(R.string.status_open);
} else {
myTextView.setText(R.string.status_closed);
}

}
});







connected = false;

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
}

}


socket.close();
Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");


} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
connected = false;
}
}
}
}
```

So my 2 questions are:

1. I have no idea how to get my buttons to interact with the socket where I send commands to my server. After I connect, I have (4) buttons that need to send various commands through the socket (which is running in a separate thread that was kicked off by clicking on the 'connect' button I have). (Look for the '// CODE HERE FOR STATUS REQUEST BUTTON?' comments for where I was expecting to put the code for the various buttons)
2. I need to move the

   'handler.post(new Runnable() {'

block of code into my main loop:

```
(while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
total.append(line);
Log.d("Server response", line.toString());
}
```

However, when I do that, and change:

```
if (total.toString().contentEquals("status:open")) {
```

to

```
if (line.toString().contentEquals("status:open")) {
```

(because I want to actually only read one line at a time),
Eclipse complains with the following message:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable line inside an inner class defined in a different method

And if I try to change the line above that...:
    String line;
to
    static String line;

Eclipse complains on the next line:

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

saying:
The final local variable line may already have been assigned

I can't even believe I've gotten this far as I'm a complete newbie, but now I've hit a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question: create a new `final` to use in your runnable

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
    Log.d("Server response", line.toString());
    final String status = line;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (status.contentEquals("status:open")) {
                myTextView.setText(R.string.status_open);
            } else {
                myTextView.setText(R.string.status_closed);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For your first question:
You've picked quite a complicated task. Your Thread needs to check some condition that you set from outside so the thread can decide what he needs to do next. From those buttons you could change e.g. an [AtomicInteger](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) that is 0 as long as there is nothing to do, 1 if you want to switch on the light, 2 ... etc

Your Thread would check the value, reset it to 0 (in one `.getAndSet(0)`) and do what he is supposed to do.

Edit: that's how it would look like

**the Thread**

```
public class LoopingNetworkThread extends Thread {
    public static final int TASK_END = -1;
    public static final int TASK_NOOP = 0;
    public static final int TASK_LIGHTS_ON = 1;
    public static final int TASK_LIGHTS_OFF = 2;

    private final AtomicInteger mNextTask = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /* Executed in this threads context */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        openSocket();
        int currentTask;
        while ((currentTask = mNextTask.getAndSet(TASK_NOOP)) != TASK_END) {
            switch (currentTask) {
                case TASK_LIGHTS_ON:
                    sendLightsOn();
                    break;
                case TASK_LIGHTS_OFF:
                    sendLightsOff();
                    break;
                default:
                    keepAlive();
                    break;
            }
            // depending on your requirements sleep some time inbetween.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        // the while ends once you set task to TASK_END
        closeSocket();
    }

    private void openSocket() {  }
    private void closeSocket() {  }
    private void keepAlive() {  }
    private void sendLightsOn() {  }
    private void sendLightsOff() {  }

    /* Executed in a different thread context */
    public int setNextTask(int task){
        // return what we overwrite here, maybe that is useful.
        return mNextTask.getAndSet(task);
    }
}
```

**your Activity**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private LoopingNetworkThread mThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mThread = new LoopingNetworkThread();
        View startButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        View stopButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mThread.start();
            }
        });
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mThread.setNextTask(LoopingNetworkThread.TASK_END);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. First question: done, no more problems. Thanks.

Comment: For my 2nd one though, thank you for the idea/solution. I am attempting to implement the AtomicInteger, but I think I'm doing something wrong. I'm sorry, this comment thing isn't very friendly...i'm going to use the 'answer your question' link.

Comment: That's not an unfriendly comment :) see Edit, maybe that explains it a bit better.

Comment: Hi @zapl, what are you referring to? Hey, it looks like my original post was edited by @Lucifer? How come? What was edited? I also have a new problem...see my latest posting below..

Comment: I just noticed you added some more code @zapl...maybe that will help me if I can figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: I am referring to the bottom part in my answer that starts with "Edit: that's how it would look like". It's an example that does what I meant in the AtomicInteger part. No idea what the edit in your post is about.

Comment: Oh ok, but I was just wondering why you said 'That's not an unfriendly comment' ... I'm pretty new to this forum and was hoping I didn't click on something to give you bad 'feedback'. ;)

Comment: You said "I'm sorry, this comment thing isn't very friendly." So I said "no it's not unfriendly" - meaning your comment. But I guess you meant the comment system isn't friendly and not your own comment is unfriendly. Sry for confusing you :)

Comment: Ohhh ok. I see...yeah I was referring to the commenting system. No problem. :) (btw, I commented below on your latest comment (below) too.)

Comment: I was wondering - it looks like that you have the thread in a completely different class/java file...is there an advantage to doing it that way over the way I have it? (The way I have it in my original posting). And it looks like for your example you're using 'pseudo code' for parts of it like the socket part. I see that it looks like all the action happens in your 'while' statement...which I'm still not sure how that works - I don't fully understand the  `while ((currentTask = mNextTask.getAndSet(TASK_NOOP)) != TASK_END)` line. I'm not sure how you would receive socket messages.

Comment: The way I have it (I grabbed it from someone else's example somewhere on the net) is: `while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
total.append(line);
Log.d("Server response", line.toString());
// This is where the main code goes to respond to messages from the server through the socket
}
`

Comment: Different class / file looks cleaner once you have a bigger project. The pseudo code is where write and maybe read responses. I don't know how your protocol works but maybe you can simply read everytime at the beginning of the loop and decide what you send at the end of the loop based on what command you have